# Poles of not so simple function

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, roots

If we consider the complex function
$$ 
f(s)=\dfrac{1}{(1+\frac{l^3}{12}) s^2 + \frac{l^2}{2}s\sqrt{1+ms}+lms+l},
$$
where $l,\,m>0$. How can I prove that its poles $p$ are such that $\Re (p)<0$?

Comment: To start there will be issues would be when the denominator is $0$.  So it is a quadratic polynomial in $s$.  Can find the roots using quadratic formula.  Other than that, there might be issues depending on what branch you take for the square roots

Comment: @NazimJ, there is another $s$ in the square root, so it is harder than quadratic..

Comment: Ah missed that.  So in order to attempt my idea above, you would multiply top and bottom by denominator with negate square root $() - () \sqrt{1+ms}$, which will get messy and might be hard to solve :(